# Virtualbox installation - wants media/cdrom but my Ubuntu intalled from USB

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install VirtualBox, but it is asking for me to insert a cd into media/cdrom.  However, I installed my Ubuntu OS from a USB.  It does not allow me to change location.  How do I make it read my OS install info from my USB?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Virtualbox of using a raw disk. Details can be found here... 
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk

This is what you're looking for out of that page...

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk
  -rawdisk /dev/sda
```